# TypeError: flag1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw flag1 at the location stored in positions:

```
        turtle.setpos(positions[0][:2]) #MAKE A = 1 
    turtle.write('ABC', align='center', font=20)
    turtle.dot(20, "blue")
    occupied[0].append((positions[0][2], positions[0][3]))
    flag1((positions[0][2], positions[0][3]))
```

But I receive the following error

```
    flag1((positions[0][2], positions[0][3]))
TypeError: flag1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

The list can be seen as:

```
    positions = [
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'A', 7],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, 3*VERTICAL, 'G', 7],
    [-3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'A', 1],
    [3*HORIZONTAL, -3*VERTICAL, 'G', 1]
]

occupied = [  # To store the grid occupied
    [('A', 7)],
    [('G', 7)],
    [('A', 1)],
    [('G', 1)]
]
```

Comment: I'm guessing `flag1` wants the arguments as 2 separate ones, not a `tuple`. Try `flag1(positions[0][2], positions[0][3])`.

Comment: ah yeh thats correct, thanks. but now I get the error:     return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float' .I think that I need to convert  the string values to integers?

Comment: I'd say convert them to `float`s instead, (so wrap `self[...]` in a `float` call). But if you have other questions, make sure to ask a new one with debugging details.

Comment: ok thanks for the help ill try debug this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `x` and `y` parameters are in a tuple. This means that `flag1` takes that tuple as the parameter for `x`, leaving nothing for the `y` parameter. So you need to remove the inner brackets to separate the arguments:

```
flag1(positions[0][2], positions[0][3])
```

This should pass a parameter of `x` separately to `y`.